# Android ThreadSafeClientConnManager Timeouts?

Tags: android, multithreading, httprequest

I'm using a ThreadSafeClientConnManager to perform simultaneous requests in background threads on Android, set up with:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
registry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

ClientConnectionManager connman = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
client = new DefaultHttpClient(connman, params);
```

And executing requests with (note that I'm using outh-signpost):

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://" + API_HOST + "/" + API_VERSION + path);
OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(key, secret);
consumer.sign(request);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

The problem is that after a while I start getting

```
java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
```

Do I need to do something to explicitly release the connection after the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the usage guide of apache httpclient, you need to make sure to consume all content on any pooled resource to guarantee it returns to the pool to be available for other threads later on -

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.0.1/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d0e244

In case there's an exception thrown by the underlying library, it is best to abort the HttpMethod that you were trying to run, in which case the connection will be terminated.